# Creating in img file (bmp,jpg,png) from html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a page that includes a number of canvas elements each with its own shape (rec,line etc...) and also css3 properties (rotate,deg,transform etc...).
i need to take that html element or page and render it as an image file including all the child elements and their styling.

- html2canvas.js has a lot of problems rendering css3 properties so that option is off the table.
- and the elements i want to convert to an image are an array of html elements (div,canvas,p,video etc...) so a screenshot of a canvas element want do.

is there a solution for this problem???
i must convert it to an img i dont have any other alternative !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this.
Here is an example in node:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.org/', function() {
    var clipRect = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.getElementById('myID').getBoundingClientRect();
    });

    page.clipRect = {
        top:    clipRect.top,
        left:   clipRect.left,
        width:  clipRect.width,
        height: clipRect.height
    };

    page.render('myCapture.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This will go to `example.org` and take a screenshot of everything inside `#myID`

Comment: sorry this needs Microsoft Visual C++ and all kinds off instalation that we cant handle. i need a pure JS or JS library solution to this problem. im trying to do this on the client side.

Comment: It does not need Microsoft Visual C++.